# Convexity of L2 norm composed with affine transformation of a component wise convex function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

It is not too difficult to show that $$||A\vec{x}-\vec{y}||_2^2$$ is convex with respect to $\vec{x}$. But, if we assume that $\vec{x} = \vec{f}(\vec{z})$, where each $f_i(\vec{z})$ is convex, is there anything we can say about $$||A\vec{f}(\vec{z})-\vec{y}||_2^2$$ being convex with respect to $\vec{z}$?

Comment: How are you defining a convex vector-valued function $f$?

Comment: This simply isn't true in general.  In one dimension, let $A=1$, $f(z)=z^{2}$, and $y=1$.  Then $\| Af(z)-y\|^{2}=(z^{2}-1)^{2}$, which isn't convex.

Comment: @Jose27 $f$ is a component wise exponential (i.e. $[f(\vec{x})]_i = exp(x_i)$).